# Use Django with SSL in order to integrate PayPal

Tags: python, django, ssl, paypal

I want to use PayPal in a Django Project and in order to do this I need Django to work with TSL 1.2. Since I haven't worked with such encryption yet, I need advice on how to setup Django in a way that works with an https version that works with PayPal. I already have a working ssl certificate and was able to use django-sslserver to make Django work with https, but PayPal still does not work with it. Could someone give a hint were I should be looking into for this kind of thing?

Comment: please try to be more specific: what part fails, do you get some error message?

Comment: I now that the part that fails is that PayPal uses TSL 1.2 which the django-sslserver module propably does not support and thus the connection is rejected by the paypal servers when trying  to use the PayPal IPN notify option. So I want to know how I can run my django web server in a way that supports that encryption protocol.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a self-signed SSL certificate, then this is not going to work. You can get a free SSL certificate at Let's encrypt: https://letsencrypt.org/.

If you use the Javascript API your site has to be served over HTTPS as well because of CORS.

Comment: I dont have a self signed certificate, I have a hosted one that does actually work.